# Manipulate a list based on another list

Tags: python

I have a list of English Words(list2) and I want to remove the words from the list that contain the alphabets/letters in (list1)

For this example:

```
list1 = ['A','B']
list2 = ['AARON', 'ABAFT', 'ABASE', 'ABASK', 'ABAVE', 'ABBAS', 'ABBIE', 'ABDAL', 'ABEAM', 'ABELE', 'ABIDE', 'ABIES', 'ABKAR', 'ABLOW', 'ABNER', 'ABODE', 'ABOHM']
```

I want to write a loop to remove all elements as they contain either A or B.
The result should be an empty list.

```
list1 = ['A','B']
list2 = ['AARON', 'ABAFT', 'ABASE', 'ABASK', 'ABAVE', 'ABBAS', 'ABBIE', 'ABDAL', 'ABEAM', 'ABELE', 'ABIDE', 'ABIES', 'ABKAR', 'ABLOW', 'ABNER', 'ABODE', 'ABOHM']

for x in list1:
   for y in list2:
     if x in y:
       list2.remove(y)

print(list2)
```

I was expecting an empty list but the result was:

```
['ABASK', 'ABDAL', 'ABIES', 'ABODE']
```

Comment: Removing elements from a list whilst iterating over it is separately a bug which you want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by tripleee, changing a list while iterating over it can cause trouble. I'd suggest using a list comprehension and `set` to check for intersecting characters:

```py
# Or list1 = {'A','B'}
list1 = set(list1)

# returns empty list
[w for w in list2 if not list1.intersection(w)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a regex match if the list1 is not complex. An example approach can be like below:

```
import re
matcher = re.compile("|".join(list1))
list2 = [s for s in list2 if not matcher.search(s)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a compositions of built-in functions, [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

`filter` return a generator so should be casted to `list`.

```
list1 = ['A','B']
list2 = ['ARON', 'ABAFT', 'ABASE', 'ABASK', 'ABAVE', 'ABBAS', 'ABBIE', 'ABDAL', 'ABEAM', 'ABELE', 'ABIDE', 'ABIES', 'ABKAR', 'ABLOW', 'ABNER', 'ABODE', 'ABOHM']

a = filter(lambda s: not any(map(s.__contains__, list1)), list2)
print(list(a))
```